# saving and retrieving multipart files inside the src/main/resources/static folder in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have tried this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public void saveFilm(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
                                           throws Exception 
 { 
  File convFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/upload/
                            "+file.getOriginalFilename()); 
  convFile.createNewFile(); 
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);

  fos.write(file.getBytes()); 

  fos.close(); 
  System.out.println(convFile); 
 } 
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter 
 { 
@Override public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) 
{ 
    registry.addResourceHandler("/upload/*").addResourceLocations
    ("/upload/", "src/main/resources/static/upload/", 
    "classpath:src/main/resources/static/upload/", 
    "file:src/main/resources/static/upload/", 
    "/src/main/resources/static/upload/",
    "file:/src/main/resources/static/upload/",
    "classpath:/src/main/resources/static/upload/", 
    "upload/"); 
    } 
}
```

and when i just tried to package using maven and then run on server the files get uploaded successfully in the folder but when i tried accessing using
http://localhost:8080/upload/image.jpg it cant be accessed and showing 404 error.

Comment: No it won't... It isn't uploaded to the location you thin it is. You cannot upload to directories inside your application.

Comment: when i store my files it will be stored in the heroku server in a folder named /app/src/main/resources/static/upload/image.jpg  but i cant acess this folder, is there any way to acess the files from her ?